# A series from a physics problem: $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2k + 1}e^{-(2k + 1)\pi x/a}\sin\left( \frac{(2k + 1)\pi y}{a}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

How might we show that $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2k + 1}e^{-(2k + 1)\pi x/a}\sin\left( \frac{(2k + 1)\pi y}{a}\right)  = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\sin(\pi y/a)}{\sinh(\pi x/a)} \right) $$
where $x, y$ are independent variables and $a$ is a parameter?

This arose in the solution to Laplace's equation. My text asserted this without proof, so I'm curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on Mhenni Benghorbal's answer, the Maclaurin series of the [inverse hyperbolic tangent function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html) is  $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1} = \text{artanh} (z) \, , \ |z| <1.$$

So assuming $x, a >0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, we get

$$ \begin{align} &\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2k + 1}e^{-(2k + 1)\pi x/a}\sin\left( \frac{(2k + 1)\pi y}{a}\right) \\ &= \text{Im}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2k + 1}e^{-(2k + 1)\pi x/a} e^{i(2k+1) \pi y /a} \\ &= 2 \ \text{Im} \ \text{artanh} \left(e^{- \pi x /a} e^{- i \pi y/a} \right) \\ &= \ \text{Im} \left( \text{Log} (1+e^{- \pi x/a} e^{i \pi y/a}) - \text{Log}(1-e^{-\pi x /a} e^{i \pi y /a})\right) \\&= \arctan \left(  \frac{e^{- \pi x/a}\sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{1 + e^{- \pi x/a} \cos (\frac{\pi y}{a})}  \right) - \arctan\left( \frac{-e^{- \pi x /a} \sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{1 - e^{- \pi x /a}\cos (\frac{\pi y}{a})}  \right) \tag{1} \\ &= \arctan \left( \frac{\sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{e^{\pi x /a} +\cos (\frac{\pi y}{a})}  \right) + \arctan\left( \frac{\sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{e^{\pi x /a} - \cos (\frac{\pi y}{a})}  \right)  \\ &= \arctan \left(\frac{2 e^{\pi x/a} \sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{e^{2 \pi x/a} - \cos^{2} (\frac{\pi y}{a}) - \sin^{2} (\frac{\pi y}{a})} \right) \tag{2}\\   &= \arctan \left( \frac{2e^{\pi x/a} \sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{e^{2 \pi x/a}-1} \right)  \\ &= \arctan \left( \frac{\sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{\sinh (\frac{\pi x}{a})}\right). \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$  The points $1+e^{- \pi x/a} e^{i \pi y/a}$ and $ 1-e^{- \pi x/a} e^{i \pi y/a}$ are in the right half-plane.

$(2)$ Since $$ \left|\frac{\sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{e^{\pi x/a} + \cos (\frac{\pi y}{a})} \left(\frac{\sin (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{e^{\pi x/a} - \cos (\frac{\pi y}{a})} \right) \right| = \frac{1-\cos^{2} (\frac{\pi y}{a})}{e^{2 \pi x/a} - \cos^{2} (\frac{\pi y}{a})}  < 1, $$ we can use the formula $$\arctan(x+y) = \arctan \left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy} \right).$$

Comment: I gave the hints for the OP!

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** You need the  identities

$$ \sin t = \frac{ e^{it} - e^{-it}}{2i} $$

and

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  t^{2k} = \frac{1}{1-t^2} .$$

Comment: @downvoters: What's the downvote for? This is the first answer to be posted and you can see that the othdr answer used it to give the full answer?  So who do you think deserves the credit?

Comment: @moderators: you can see what's happening! I am putting these comments just for honest users know what's going on.