# Converting of a exponential form of a complex function to trigonometric

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

everybody.

I was reading the classical electrodynamics book written by Jackson, but at the derivation of formula of (65.2), I got a problem. It is written that by considering 
\begin{align}
Z=e^{(\frac{i\pi}{a})(x+iy)}
\end{align}
 in the potential relation
\begin{align}
\phi(x,y)=\frac{2V}{\pi} \text{Im} \left(\ln \left( \frac{1+Z}{1-Z}  \right) \right),
\end{align}
we will obtain 
\begin{align}
\phi(x,y) = \frac{2V}{\pi} \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)}{\sinh\left(\frac{\pi y}{a}\right)} \right).
\end{align}
My problem is that I don't know how that last equation has been derived. It's a kind of you if you help me.

Best wishes.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880631/how-did-they-sum-this-infinite-series-sum-n-1-3-5-frac1n-e-fracn-pi?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$Z=e^{\frac{i \pi  (x+i y)}{a}}\implies \frac{1+Z}{1-Z}=i \cot \left(\frac{\pi  (x+i y)}{2 a}\right)$$ $$\log\left(\frac{1+Z}{1-Z} \right)=\log\left(i \cot \left(\frac{\pi  (x+i y)}{2 a}\right)\right)$$
$$\text{Im} \left(\ln \left( \frac{1+Z}{1-Z}  \right) \right)=\arg \left(i \cot \left(\frac{\pi  (x+i y)}{2 a}\right)\right)$$ Just continue.